# Symfony serializer and ManyToMany setter

Tags: symfony, deserialization

I have two entity. 
`Book` and `Author`

```
class Book
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private int $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private string $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Author", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="books_authors",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="book_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="author_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *  )
     * @var PersistentCollection|ArrayCollection
     */
    private $authors;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->authors = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAuthors()
    {
        return $this->authors;
    }

    public function setAuthors($authors)
    {
        $this->authors = $authors;
    }

    public function addAuthor($author){
        if(!$this->authors->contains($author))
            $this->authors->add($author);
    }

    public function  removeAuthor($author){
        if($this->authors->contains($author)){
            $this->authors->removeElement($author);
        }
    }
}
```

In BookController i try create new book and use Serializer
book body like

```
{
  "name:"book name",
  "authors":[
    1,
    2
  ]
}
```

In controller

```
$serializer = new Serializer([new ObjectNormalizer()], [new JsonEncoder()]);
$book = $this->serializer->deserialize($request->getContent(), Book::class, 'json');
        try{
            $this->entityManager->persist($book);
            $this->entityManager->flush();
        } catch (UniqueConstraintViolationException $exception){
            return new JsonResponse('already exist', JsonResponse::HTTP_FOUND);
        }
```

but on flush() I have exception:

> Expected value of type "App\Entity\Author" for association field "App\Entity\Book#$authors", got "integer" instead.

because `book->authors` now is an `id` collection, but entity collection needle.

I have some variants of resolve this, but what is the best way for create and update entity?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create EntityNormalizer like this:
[Medium post][1]

```
class EntityNormalizer extends ObjectNormalizer implements DenormalizableInterface
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, ?ClassMetadataFactoryInterface $classMetadataFactory = null, ?NameConverterInterface $nameConverter = null, ?PropertyAccessorInterface $propertyAccessor = null, ?PropertyTypeExtractorInterface $propertyTypeExtractor = null)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        parent::__construct($classMetadataFactory, $nameConverter, $propertyAccessor, $propertyTypeExtractor);
    }

    public function supportsNormalization($data, $format = null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public function supportsDenormalization($data, $type, $format = null)
    {
        return !$this->em->getMetadataFactory()->isTransient($type) && (is_string($data) || is_numeric($data));
    }

    public function denormalize($data, $class, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        return $this->em->find($class, $data);
    }
}


  [1]: https://medium.com/cloudstek/using-the-symfony-serializer-with-doctrine-relations-69ecb17e6ebd
```